# How to get the CPU information of a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

In my server, there exists several CPUs (0-7). I need run parallel code, and each process affiliate with one CPU, so how do I know the CPU information for each process?

For example, if two processes (#0 and #1) exist, and process #0 uses CPU 5 and process #1 uses CPU 7.

how do I know that by programming in C or Fortran?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [sched_getcpu()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html) call.

Keep in mind that a process/thread can be scheduled freely to run on any available cpu/core, so one of your processes could run on core 1 one second, and on core 2 the next milisecond. You can restrict which processors a process is allowed to run on with [sched_setaffinity](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)()

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any system call on Linux that will give you general information about what CPU a thread in running on. @nos is correct that sched_getcpu() will tell you which CPU a thread is running on, but only for the calling context.

You can do this by querying the `/proc` file system. However, if you find yourself building your application around this functionality, it is likely that you need to reexamine your design.

The file `/proc/<pid>/stats` contains a field that provides you with the last CPU the process ran on. You would just need to parse the output. (use `man proc` to see the field list).

Answer (score 1):

In general it is the task of the operating system to abstract such things from applications.
Normally I see my applications (as simple as doing a grep on a *huge* file) change CPU core every once in a while.

Now if you want to force an application on a specific core you can manually set the CPU affinity.

I've written some pretty strange software in the past and I've never had the desire to know and/or control this.

Why would you *want* to know?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to change the CPU affinity, because a process can migrate between processors: [CPU Affinity](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6799) (Linux Journal, 2003).

Answer (score 0):

More generally, why do you want to know? The Linux kernel is very good at scheduling processes/threads to make the best use of the available cores.

Comment: since I want to change the cpu speed dynamically and do some research work